# Arduino Nano BLE 33 Sense and DS18B20 not working

Tags: c++, arduino, nano

My issue is related to Arduino Nano Sense BLE and DS18B20 sensor (waterproof version) are not working together.

What I tried so far. I performed a test on UNO to isolate possible powering and sensor fault. Test looked as follows:

**Connection of DS18B20**

**Black** > **GDN**

**Red** > **3V**

**Yellow** > **D2**

Last two connected via 2k2 resistor (2k2 instead 4k7 as I use 3V).

Then, to exclude possible coding mistakes I used ready example:

```
// Include the libraries we need
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

// Data wire is plugged into port 2 on the Arduino
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 2

// Setup a oneWire instance to communicate with any OneWire devices (not just Maxim/Dallas temperature ICs)
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);

// Pass our oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature.
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

/*
 * The setup function. We only start the sensors here
 */
void setup(void)
{
  // start serial port
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Dallas Temperature IC Control Library Demo");

  // Start up the library
  sensors.begin();
}

/*
 * Main function, get and show the temperature
 */
void loop(void)
{
  // call sensors.requestTemperatures() to issue a global temperature
  // request to all devices on the bus
  Serial.print("Requesting temperatures...");
  sensors.requestTemperatures(); // Send the command to get temperatures
  Serial.println("DONE");
  // After we got the temperatures, we can print them here.
  // We use the function ByIndex, and as an example get the temperature from the first sensor only.
  Serial.print("Temperature for the device 1 (index 0) is: ");
  Serial.println(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0));
  delay(1000);
}
```

**Result?** works perfectly fine.

Then I switched to Nano Sense BLE board. without disconnecting the sensor I just switched connection on board's end and attached GDN, 3.3V and D2.

Result, -127. When trying to find DS18B20 address the result is none. I suspect board's pins order issue or Dallas/OneWire lib issue.

I also tried other libs to handle DS18B20, none works, and I tried like 3-4 of them. I noticed there is few topics around internet regarding nano series and none are resolved. I found also IoT and Every has the same problem.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: I managed to find out that OneWire lib is not yet compatible with Nano Sense BLE. Author of the lib is aware of it but no ETA for implementation support. Dedicated Mbed solution is here: https://os.mbed.com/teams/Maxim-Integrated/code/OneWire/ but would require analyze, adaptation and tests.

Answer (score 0):

The issue of getting -127 from DS18B20 is because sensor might be disconnected or didn't get 3.3V or 300mA current properly from board. So make sure your pins connected correctly. you can test it with you DMM by checking short between pin and wires. Sometime it might be a library issue. you need to install the latest version of onewire and Dallas temperature library.